# Why does Anaconda install a lot of unnecessary packages? Is this a settings issue that can be solved or am I not understanding conda env properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, virtualenv

I have been studying some python lately and I think I have understood the "environments" concept (mainly though a pip youtube tutorial, and just to share with whoever's in need: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2ZN104hIcc), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5vscPTWKOk&t=323s))

I tried the same set of concept understanding, this time using Anaconda ([source](https://pythonistaplanet.com/how-to-create-a-django-project-in-anaconda-very-easily/)), and these are my commands:

```
conda create -n testconda python=3.8 anaconda
```

(...yes ... enter... yes again...)

```
conda activate testconda
```

and I noticed it started installing a ton of packages, which I know some of them (like "Flask"), that aren't necessary.

*(`conda list` output in the end of the post)*

So as far as I know (following the youtube tutorial I previously attached to my post), pip installs only required packages (preparing my env and latter - depending on what I install in my env).

Why is Anaconda installing all these packages? 
Is there a way to change the settings to only required packages?
I get that some packages should be installed for the environment to work, but I think that some are not...

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0  
anaconda                  2020.02                  py38_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py38_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py38_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py38_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py38_0  
astropy                   4.0              py38h7b6447c_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py38_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py38_2  
beautifulsoup4            4.8.2                    py38_0  
bitarray                  1.2.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py38_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                      py_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd408876_0  
bokeh                     1.4.0                    py38_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py38_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py38heb32a55_0  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2019.11.28               py38_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py38h2e261b9_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003  
click                     7.0                        py_0  
cloudpickle               1.3.0                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cryptography              2.8              py38h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.68.0               hbc83047_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0  
cython                    0.29.15          py38he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py38h7b6447c_0  
dask                      2.11.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.11.0                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.1                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0  
distributed               2.11.0                   py38_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py38_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py38_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py38h7b6447c_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.7.9                    py38_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
fsspec                    0.6.2                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py38_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.3.7            py38h7b6447c_1  
glib                      2.63.1               h5a9c865_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py38hd5f6e3b_3  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py38h7b6447c_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h7918eee_0  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.0.1                      py_0  
hypothesis                5.5.4                      py_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.8                   py38_1000  
imageio                   2.6.1                    py38_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py38_0  
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0  
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py38h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.12.0           py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py38_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.14.1                   py38_0  
jeepney                   0.4.2                      py_0  
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0  
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json5                     0.9.1                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py38_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.4                    py38_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.1                    py38_0  
jupyterlab                1.2.6              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
keyring                   21.1.0                   py38_0  
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py38he6710b0_0  
krb5                      1.17.1               h173b8e3_0      
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py38h7b6447c_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5  
libcurl                   7.68.0               h20c2e04_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                he6710b0_0  
libssh2                   1.8.2                h1ba5d50_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_0  
libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h7d1a2b0_0  
llvmlite                  0.31.0           py38hd408876_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py38_1  
lxml                      4.5.0            py38hefd8a0e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py38_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py38hef1b27d_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py38_1  
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h7b6447c_1000  
mkl                       2020.0                      166  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py38ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py38h962f231_0  
mock                      4.0.1                      py_0  
more-itertools            8.2.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py38_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py38hfd86e86_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py38_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_0  
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_0  
networkx                  2.4                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py38_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py38_2  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py38_0  
numba                     0.48.0           py38h0573a6f_0  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py38h423224d_0  
numpy                     1.18.1           py38h4f9e942_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py38hde5b4d6_1  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                       py_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.3                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h7b6447c_4  
packaging                 20.1                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.1            py38h0573a6f_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py38_1  
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
patchelf                  0.10                 he6710b0_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py38_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py38_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py38_0  
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py38_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py38_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1000  
pillow                    7.0.0            py38hb39fc2d_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py38_1  
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py38_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py38_0  
ply                       3.11                     py38_0  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.3                      py_0  
psutil                    5.6.7            py38h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py38_0  
py                        1.8.1                      py_0  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py38_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h7b6447c_0  
pycparser                 2.19                       py_0  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py38h1ba5d50_0  
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py38_0  
pygments                  2.5.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.4.4                    py38_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py38he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py38_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.6                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h05f1152_4  
pyrsistent                0.15.7           py38h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py38h9fd0a39_0  
pytest                    5.3.5                    py38_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.2              py38h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.8.0                      py_0  
pytest-astropy-header     0.1.2                      py_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.5.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py38_0  
python                    3.8.1                h0371630_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0  
python-language-server    0.31.7                   py38_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py38_7  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
pyxdg                     0.26                       py_0  
pyyaml                    5.3              py38h7b6447c_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py38he6710b0_0  
qdarkstyle                2.8                        py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.1                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.6.0                      py_1  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py38_1  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.16.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.9.3                    py38_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py38h7b6447c_0  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py38h0573a6f_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py38hd81dba3_0  
scipy                     1.4.1            py38h0b6359f_0  
seaborn                   0.10.0                     py_0  
secretstorage             3.1.2                    py38_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py38_0  
setuptools                45.2.0                   py38_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py38_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py38_0  
sip                       4.19.13          py38he6710b0_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py38_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.1                      py_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py38_0  
soupsieve                 1.9.5                    py38_0  
sphinx                    2.4.0                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py38_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.0                      py_0  
spyder                    4.0.1                    py38_0  
spyder-kernels            1.8.1                    py38_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.13           py38h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               h7b6447c_0  
statsmodels               0.11.0           py38h7b6447c_0  
sympy                     1.5.1                    py38_0  
tbb                       2020.0               hfd86e86_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py38_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py38h7b6447c_3  
tqdm                      4.42.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py38_0  
ujson                     1.35             py38h7b6447c_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py38_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py38_0  
watchdog                  0.10.2                   py38_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.8                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py38h7b6447c_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py38_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.7                      py_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py38_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      2.2.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't install the "anaconda" package:

```
conda create -n testconda python=3.8
```